# Modal view for iPad in iOS 7

Tags: ios, ipad

Does anyone know how modal views will be on the iPad once iOS 7 comes out?

I have a button on the screen that triggers a login-type form. On the iPhone a normal modal or pull-up view works great but how would this look/behave on iOS 7.

Comment: This might help you to some extent: http://www.creativebloq.com/apple/designers-need-know-ios7-6133221

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/etc/redirect/WWDR/iOSUITransitionGuide go to page 46 it goes over modals

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: there's no required behavior change from iOS 6 to iOS 7 for modal screens - only the recommended styles (and how 'tint' color) changes.

See the [Temporary Views](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/TempViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH11-SW4) page in the [iOS 7 UI Transition Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174). Modal Views are the last element covered on that page. One small change you may want to take advantage of, straight out of the documentation:

> In iOS 7, you can use a custom animator object and an optional
>   interactive controller object to manage modal presentation.

Links to those resources are included on that page (see first link).